# How to get how many times an element occurs in ArrayList

Tags: java, list, collections

```
    for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i){
        oc = Collections.frequency(arr, arr.get(i));
        System.out.print(oc + " "+ arr.get(i) +" ");
        arr.remove(i);
    }
```

The main idea is to output how many times every element in sequence occurs.
For example

```
1 1 2 3 3 3 10 10
```

here the output is

```
2 1 1 2 3 3 2 10
```

It is like two ones, one element of two, 3 elements of 3, and 2 elements of 10.

This is buggy, for example it is not working for this case

```
1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1
```

What is wrong? Any other algorithms?

Comment: define "not working"

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that inside the `for` loop you remove an element (`arr.remove(i)`) so the remaining elements get shifted and when `i` gets incremented, you skip one element. Removing an element also changes its frequency, so don't do that.

Do something like this:

```
List<String> arr = Arrays.asList("a", "a", "b", "a", "a");

for (String s : arr)
    System.out.println("element: " + s
        + ", count: " + Collections.frequency(arr, s));
```

If an element is in the list multiple times, this will print it multiple times. Use a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) to remember if an element was already printed, and do not print it again:

```
List<String> arr = Arrays.asList("a", "a", "b", "a", "a");

Set<String> printed = new HashSet<>();
for (String s : arr) {
    if (printed.add(s)) // Set.add() also tells if the element was in the Set!
        System.out.println("element: " + s
            + ", count: " + Collections.frequency(arr, s));
}
```

**Output:**

```
element: a, count: 4
element: b, count: 1
```

### Alternative

Alternatively you can add all elements of the original list to a `Set` (which will ensure every element is contained only once), and iterate over this set, but count in the original array:

```
List<String> arr = Arrays.asList("a", "a", "b", "a", "a");

for (String s : new HashSet<>(arr))
    System.out.println("element: " + s
        + ", count: " + Collections.frequency(arr, s));
```

**Output: same.** But note that this might result in different order of the output as `Set`s in Java are not ordered.

Answer (score 0):

I would work with a HashMap, whereas the meaning is element -> count! pseudo:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
 for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i){
    Integer x = counts.get(arr.get(i));
    if (x==null) counts.put(arr.get(i), 1);
    else counts.put(arr.get(i), x+1);
}
```

after this, your hashmap holds all elements and their count

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    List a = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1, 3, 1);
    Collections.sort(a);
    Object o = a.get(0);
    int n = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++) {
        Object t = a.get(i);
        if (o.equals(t)) {
            n++;
        } else {
            System.out.println(o + " - " + n);
            n = 1;
            o = t;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(o + " - " + n);
```

output

```
1 - 3
2 - 1
3 - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and smart way to do this would be to 
1) Sort the arrayList using Collections.sort
2) get first index using indexOf()  and get last index using lastIndexOf() method 
3) difference of 2 index will give you number of occurrences of given object in the ArrayList.